# working rate problem two people writing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two people $A$ and $B$ are writing questions for a test.

$B$ is writing in $3$ days the same amount of questions as $A$ writing in $4$ days.

$A$ worked 3 days more than $B$.

After they finished working separately, they meet and worked together, but their working rate
was limited to the rate of the slower one among them.

They worked together $4$ days more than the time that $A$ worked alone and the finished together $150$ question.

If the sum of all question that they wrote in separately is $\cdot \frac{93}{57}$ more that the sum of questions they wrote together, How many questions each of them wrote separately and how much time each of them worked separately?

I got messy algebra and i don't know how to solve.

I'd be glad for help.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

The essential point is to introduce the right quantities as unknowns.

Denote by $a$ and $b$ the number of problems $A$ resp. $B$ invents per day when working separately. Then denote by $d_A$, $d_B$ and $d$ the number of days the two worked separately, resp. together. From the story we then immediately deduce that
$$3b=4a, \quad d_B=d_A-3,\quad d=d_A+4\ .\tag{1}$$
Furthermore we are told that
$$d_A\>a+d_B\>b+d\>a=150\ .\tag{2}$$
Here I have interpreted the common output rate as the rate of $A$ alone; the text could also be interpreted as saying that the common output rate is only $2a$ instead of $a+b$.

Now write an equation similar to $(2)$ that implements the last condition (here it is again open to debate what is meant by "$\cdot{93\over57}$ more"). This will be equation $(3)$.

Having this use $(1)$ to eliminate $b$, $d_B$ and $d$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$. You are left with two equations in the unknowns $a$ and $d_A$, which you are hopefully able to solve. Then determine $b$, $d_B$ and $d$, so that in the end you can answer the actual questions.